# Регулярное выражение срабатывающие на первый знак

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Пишу в телеграмму бота, как можно заставить игнорировать такие сообщения?
« Менеджер», « Контракты», « Уведомления»
Которые начинаются с смайлика.
Я пытался сделать через регулярное выражение, использую библиотеку node-telegram-bot-api.

```
bot.onText(/(.+)/, (msg, match) => {
     if ((msg.text).startsWith(/^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/)) {
    return;
  }
)}
```

Вот пример моего выражения, но оно почему-то не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), к сожалению, не работает с регулярными выражениями, только со строками.

Аналог для вашей регулярки, используя [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
if (/^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/.test(msg.text)) {
```

См. также универсальный вариант с помощью Unicode property escapes: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#matching-emoji